Как ответ бота вызвать простой текстовой командой
Я хочу чтобы бот отвечал на какую то команду ответом из прошлой команды. Например есть такой код :
list_numbers = [1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7, 4, 2, 1]
print(list_numbers.count(2))

Как заставить бота ответить тем что он выдаст в print на любую команду ?

а как у вас list_numbers.count(2) выдает 2, если должно выдавать 3? И при чем тут "сколько часов"?

это вообще просто пример

исправлено и подкорректировано под мой вопрос

надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос
вот код:
list_numbers = [1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7, 4, 2, 1]
command = "hello"
botAnswer = list_numbers.count(2)
repeatAnswer = False
while True:
    userInput = input()
    if userInput == command:
        print(botAnswer)
        repeatAnswer = True
        continue
    if repeatAnswer == True:
        repeatAnswer = False
        print(botAnswer)
        continue

в переменную command пишем сообщение пользователя после которого код ещё раз выдаст ответ
в переменную botAnswer сам ответ
